# doFilter JSF User Authentication

Tags: java, jsf-2, filter

I am trying to use a doFilter and my web.xml page to force users to login to access any "secured" page.

I found an example [here](http://www.itcuties.com/j2ee/jsf-2-login-filter-example/) and I have implemented it. I am having a small issue though. When I put the filter definition into web.xml the entire website fails to load. I do believe this is because I do not have the proper class path to the java file which contains the filter.  I am showing you my web.xml page next to my project explorer. [image: Auth Filter] I am hoping you can help me with the class path needed for the `<filter-class>     </filter-class>`

I am also showing my `doFilter method`

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    UserBean userBean = (UserBean)((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getAttribute("userBean");

    if(userBean == null || !userBean.isSuccessfullLogin()){
        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath();
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/index.xhtml");
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

So far the rest of my server works, the website runs but I can not get the filter. Any suggestions are accepted!

Thank you!

Comment: Your filter is in a `Filter` folder (read `Filter` java package), your `filter-class` definition must be the fully qualified class name (FQN): `Filter.AuthenticationFilter`. Screen-shots of files are a lot less easier to read than the actual files. You should post the content of the file here next time

Comment: That is exactly what my FQN in the web.xml is set to. The filter though is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not written any filters by now, but usually if you have to define a class in web.xml, it is named as

```
package.Class
```

So if your AuthenticationFilter class is in the package "my.filter.package" like so:

```
package my.filter.package;
public class AuthenticationFilter {...}
```

the filter class declaration should be

```
<filter-class>my.filter.package.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did get it to work last night. Filters.AuthenticationFilter works. It was my url pattern that was wrong.

Instead of having my url pattern as /secured/* I needed it to be /faces/secured/*